# transform dataframe: Do you know how group string columns in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, etl

I am currently working with the next dataframe:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | some | null | something A |
| 1 | 2 | some | something B | null |

And I need the following output:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | some | something B | something A |

My problem is that I can't made a groupBy using string columns.

I tried using self joining and pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols_for_groupby = ["A", "B", "C"]
(
    df
    .groupby(cols_for_groupby)
    .agg(*[
        F.max(c).alias(c)
        for c in df.columns if c not in cols_for_groupby
    ])
)
```

If `df` is the `DataFrame` in the question, the result is:

```bash
+---+---+----+-----------+-----------+
|  A|  B|   C|          D|          E|
+---+---+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1|  2|some|something B|something A|
+---+---+----+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: WOOOOW it's work!!, Thanks PieCot. I would like to vote your solution but my reputation it's under 15.

Comment: I think you could accept the answer :)